# Add another color at other keywords in listings

Tags: listings, color

How can I add another color at other keywords?

### For example:

```
morekeywordsA={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage}=\definecolor{keywordsA}{HTML}{8A4A0B}

morekeywordsB={{,},=}=\definecolor{keywordsB}{HTML}{othercolor}
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywords}{HTML}{8A4A0B}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\definecolor{comments}{HTML}{868686}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{comments}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{arsclassica}[2012/02/21 v4.0 Customizing ClassicThesis (LP)]
\RequirePackage{classicthesis}
\RequirePackage{caption}% Caption package
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The colors are `8A4A0B` (keywords), `145680` (`{`, `}`, `=`, …), `868686` (comments) and `953838` (lengths).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks! and the background? How can I set the lengths color and the `({, }, =, …)` color with the listing package? (I have added the new color in the code)

Comment: Background is `EEEEEE`. To me it seems you need `keywordstyle=[2]\color{braces}`, `(more)keywords=[2]{\{,\},[,],(,)}` and `alsoletter={\\,\{,\},[,],(,)}`. But it doesn't work. If I add `\\RequirePackages,\\ProvidesPackage` to `morekeywords` the backslash gets colored, too. But braces don't get colored if they're not standing alone. And btw, you reset settings again (I find `basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily` three times). __Maybe you should minimize your MWE for a better chance of answers.__

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I Have simplified the code ;)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel And the color for the `\def` command color? used here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35080/whats-special-about-def-vs-def-mksp? Where do you take those colors?

Comment: `\def` is HTML color `purple` or `800080`. You can take a screenshot and inspect the image with appropriate software. You can check the the CSS file or—this is what I did—use your browser's Developer Tools. And `8pt` is colored in `953838`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you want to customize (La)TeX, it's a good idea to set `texcsstyle` to have the same color as the keywords and to use the star so that the backslash will also have the same color; regarding your issue, the braces are not really keywords; I set their style (and also for the square brackets) using `literate` (notice the `*` character in the first literate line to prevent color form appearing in comments and strings):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywords}{HTML}{8A4A0B}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{comments}{HTML}{868686}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20,105,176}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    texcsstyle=*\color{keywords},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{comments}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage,NeedsTeXFormat},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
            *{\{}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\{}}}{1}
            {\}}{{\textcolor{myblue}{\}}}}{1}
            {[}{{\textcolor{myblue}{[}}}{1}
            {]}{{\textcolor{myblue}{]}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{arsclassica}[2012/02/21 v4.0 Customizing ClassicThesis (LP)]
\RequirePackage{classicthesis}
\RequirePackage{caption}% Caption package
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer your specific question, you can use `[<number>]` both in `keywordstyle` and in `keywords`, to define different keyword sets with their own style; a little example

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywords}{HTML}{8A4A0B}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{orange},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage},
    keywords=[2]{Some,Other,Keywords},
    keywords=[3]{and,another,test},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
Some Other Keywords
and another test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To apply color to lengths, one can escape to LaTeX (this however won't work for in-line listings):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywords}{HTML}{8A4A0B}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{comments}{HTML}{868686}
\definecolor{lengthcolor}{RGB}{200,40,150}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20,105,176}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    texcsstyle=*\color{keywords},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{comments}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage,NeedsTeXFormat,setlength},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
            *{\{}{{{\color{myblue}{\{}}}}{1}
            {\}}{{{\color{myblue}{\}}}}}{1}
            {[}{{{\color{myblue}{[}}}}{1}
            {]}{{{\color{myblue}{]}}}}{1},
   escapeinside=!!
}

\newcommand\lencolor[1]{\textcolor{lengthcolor}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{arsclassica}[2012/02/21 v4.0 Customizing ClassicThesis (LP)]
\RequirePackage{classicthesis}
\RequirePackage{caption}% Caption package
\setlength\parskip{!\lencolor{18pt}!}
\hspace*{!\lencolor{15cm}!}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! And is also possible set a color for the lengths? like: 8pt

Comment: @FormlessCloud I guess so; right now I am busy, but as soon as I can I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks! you are too kind ! also, another thing, if I add this codes at your answer i get colored only the left brace `{)}{{\textcolor{myblue}{)}}}{1}
{(}{{\textcolor{myblue}{(}}}{1}`

Comment: @FormlessCloud I found a solution using escaping to LaTeX; perhaps there's another simpler way of doing this, so I think it's better for you to open a fresh new question with the request about adding color to lengths. In this way you might get more alternatives.

Comment: @FormlessCloud regarding the other issue (the one with literate), it seems to be a bug; there's some problem with literate and breaklines=true. I opened this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73795/3954.

Comment: @FormlessCloud I added to my answer the option to apply color to lengths escaping to LaTeX.

Comment: thanks ! the lengths cannot be recognized automatically right?

Comment: @FormlessCloud I tried to do it automatically, but I failed.

Comment: Don't worry ! thanks again ! :)

Comment: Another little question: I have noted that the braces still remain colored also if are into a commented line, is there a way to turn off their own coloration and use the comment coloration if it are into a commented line?

Comment: @FormlessCloud it's enough to add `*` to the first line of literate as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: @FormlessCloud Is there already a solution for the right brace?
`{)}{{\textcolor{myblue}{)}}}{1} {(}{{\textcolor{myblue}{(}}}{1}`

Answer (score 0):

To apply color to lengths, you can add delimiter :

```
moredelim=[is][\color{lengthcolor}\texttt]{@@}{@@}
```

Then in your listing just add before and after @@ :

```
\setlength\parskip{@@18pt@@}
```