# Problem with literate and breaklines=true in listings package

Tags: listings

As the title says, the option `breaklines=true` seems to have an undesired interaction when using `literate`; in the following example the closing parenthesis doesn't get colorized

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  literate=
    {)}{{\textcolor{red}{)}}}{1}
    {(}{{\textcolor{red}{(}}}{1},
  breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
()
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Commenting out the `breaklines=true` option produces the desired result. What is producing this odd behaviour and how can it be prevented?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110641/help-defining-pdf-syntax-with-listings-package

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the `breaklines=true` option is given, a code that's executed after doing `\lst@literate` (which assigns the special meaning to the defined characters) is

```
\lst@ifbreaklines \lst@Def {`)}{\lst@breakProcessOther )}\fi
```

and this expands to

```
\lccode `\~=#1\lowercase {\def ~}{\lst@breakProcessOther )}
```

which makes the active `)` expand to

```
\lst@breakProcessOther )
```

where `)` is *not* active. All this happens when `\lsthk@SelectCharTable` is executed.

If, just for trying, I apply a patch with `etoolbox`

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{`)}{`]}{}{}
\makeatother
```

then the right parenthesis will be printed red, but a similar problem will appear with the `]` in case, say,

```
literate=
  {[}{{\textcolor{red}{[}}}{1}
  {]}{{\textcolor{red}{]}}}{1},
```

is specified (the right bracket will become a black right parenthesis, which I expected).

I believe this has to do with precautions `listings` makes in order to correctly treat parenthesized expressions. And I suspect that not much can be done about this.

If I try to patch the definition of `\lsthk@SelectCharTable` removing that conditional part, then the right parenthesis comes out red. But I don't know if other problems will arise.

Comment: Surely, the fact that `breaklines` breaks literate replacements is not the intended behaviour. Should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: @Jubobs I believe so.

Comment: There is an explanation underneath the line `\lst@ifbreaklines \lst@Def {\`)}{\lst@breakProcessOther )}\fi` in `listings.dtx`: *A bug [...] has been removed by using `\lst@ProcessOther` instead of `\lst@AppendOther`*. I guess fixing that original bug introduced another, which is the object of Gonzalo's question...