# Help defining PDF syntax with listings package

Tags: listings, pdf

I'm trying to make a pdf language definition for the listings package, but I can't get the string definition to work correctly. This is what I have defined:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{pdf}{
alsoletter={/,(,)},
morekeywords={/Type,/Outlines, /Count, /Kids, /Page,
    /Parent, /Resources, /MediaBox, /Contents, /Length, /ProcSet, /PDF, /Size,
    /Root, /Pages, /Catalog, /Font, /F1, /F2, /Text, /Subtype, /Type1, /Name,
    /BaseFont, /Helvetica-Bold, /Encoding, /MacRomanEncoding, /Helvetica},
morecomment=[l]{\%},
morestring=[s]{(}{)}
}
```

Here you can see the result:

[image]

It should either go from ( to ), or maybe from BT to ET (which is what vim does).

---

Okay. So I figured it out. For some reasons using `breaklines=true` creates this error.

Here is a minimal working example that produces the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{babel, listings, color}
\definecolor{darkviolet}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0.2} 
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.9}

\lstset{ %
    keywordstyle=\color{darkviolet},
    commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{darkblue},
    breaklines=true,% Produces the error in the highlighting
}

\lstdefinelanguage{pdf}{
    alsoletter={/},
    morekeywords={/Length, /F1},
    morecomment=[l]{\%},
    morestring=[s]{(}{)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=pdf]
%PDF-1.0

5 0 obj
<< /Length 44 >>        
stream
BT
/F1 27 Tf
100 100 Td (Hello World) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

%%EOF
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But I need to have breaklines set to true. So anybody know a reason why this is happening? Or is it just a bug in the listings package?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no solution. Maybe you are interested in minted with the language postscript: http://pygments.org/demo/82411/

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/problem-with-literate-and-breaklines-true-in-listings-package

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears top be special code "currently only for )" when breakline is active (listings.dtx 1.4, l. 12576):

```
% \begin{macro}{\lst@breakProcessOther}
% is the same as |\lst@ProcessOther| except that it also outputs the current
% token string. This inserts a potential linebreak point.
% Only the closing parenthesis uses this macro yet.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\gdef\lst@breakProcessOther#1{\lst@ProcessOther#1\lst@OutputOther}
\lst@AddToHook{SelectCharTable}
    {\lst@ifbreaklines \lst@Def{`)}{\lst@breakProcessOther)}\fi}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

There are probably better ways to remove that from the hook again, but this seems to do, when put in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\uglypatch #1\lst@ifbreaklines#2\fi#3\uglypatch{%
  \long\def\lsthk@SelectCharTable{#1#3}%
}
\lst@ifbreaklines
\expandafter\uglypatch\lsthk@SelectCharTable\uglypatch
\fi
\makeatother
```