# Latex lstlistings keywords with multiple colors

Tags: color, listings

I would like to define one of my own language using Latex `lstlistings`. And there are two types of keywords that I want to color them differently. For example, I want to paint operators in blue, such as `JOIN`, `FOREACH`, etc. And for variable types I want to paint them in red, such as `int`, `chararray`, etc. Is it possible using `\lstdefinelanguage`?

Comment: You might take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148193/how-can-i-define-multiple-identifier-classes-and-styles-in-listings) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73174/add-another-color-at-other-keywords-in-listings).

Comment: @Cragfelt Thanks for the link! It just solved my problem perfectly. I defined two sets of `keywords` and `keywordstyle` and got what I desired.

Comment: In spite of that you have solved your problem, you should post it to respond this question for others can value your work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the links provided by @Cragfelt, I just solved my problem using the following codes:

```
\definecolor{PigBlue}{RGB}{42, 0, 255}
\definecolor{PigRed}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\lstdefinelanguage{PigLatin}
{
    keywords=[1]{
        register ,define ,load ,store ,into ,using ,as ,join ,by ,foreach ,
        generate ,filter ,group ,all ,flatten ,and ,count 
    },
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{PigBlue},
    keywords=[2]{chararray ,int ,float },
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{PigRed},
    sensitive=false,
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]{--}
}
```

And after the definition I can use the language `PigLatin` anywhere in my codes. For example:

```
\lstset{language=PigLatin}
\begin{lstlisting}
    raw = LOAD 'raw' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, score:int);
\end{lstlisting}
```

And here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{PigBlue}{RGB}{42, 0, 255}
\definecolor{PigRed}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}

\lstdefinelanguage{PigLatin}
{
    keywords=[1]{
        register ,define ,load ,store ,into ,using ,as ,join ,by ,foreach ,
        generate ,filter ,group ,all ,flatten ,and ,count 
    },
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{PigBlue},
    keywords=[2]{chararray ,int ,float },
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{PigRed},
    sensitive=false,
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]{--}
}

\begin{document}
    \lstset{
        numbers=left,
        language=PigLatin
    }
    \begin{lstlisting}
raw = LOAD 'raw' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, score:int);
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. I didn't realize it was possible to define your own languages, and this was such a perfect answer. Both the code to create the language and the minimal example showing its usage. Thank you!